# redux-form with multiple errors on a single field

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Using [react-redux](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form), how do I render a list of multiple errors for a single input?

From there examples:

```
const submit = (values, dispatch) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'].includes(values.username)) {
        reject({username: 'User does not exist', _error: 'Login failed!'});
      } else if (values.password !== 'redux-form') {
        reject({password: 'Wrong password', _error: 'Login failed!'});
      } else {
        dispatch(showResults(values));
        resolve();
      }
    }, 1000); // simulate server latency
  });
};
```

Is it possible to do something as follows?

```
reject({username: ['User does not exist', 'and another error...']);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a discussion on Github about this https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/639